# PHP web app integration with Secugen Hamster Plus HSDU03P

Tags: javascript, php, fingerprint

Please i just bought a secugen hamster plus to integrate with my example web app. What i want to do is to show the scanned fingerprint in an input textbox.
I have no idea about how to do it. I tried an example code given here but didn't work. Below is the example code tried. I have installed all the necessary drivers and API for windows(64bit) but to no avail.Thanks for the help

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>ActiveX Example 1.1 of SecuGen FDx Pro SDK </title>

        <script lang=javascript>
        <!--
        var aaa = 0;
        function fnOpenDevice()
        {
            document.frmmain.objFP.DeviceID = document.frmmain.inc.value;
            document.frmmain.objFP.CodeName = document.frmmain.dev.value;
            document.frmmain.objFP.MinutiaeMode = document.frmmain.templateFormat.value;

            // template format of objVerify should be the same to those of objFP[]
            objVerify.MinutiaeMode = document.frmmain.templateFormat.value;
            return;
        }

        function fnCapture()
        {
            document.frmmain.objFP.Capture();
            var result = document.frmmain.objFP.ErrorCode;
        alert(result);
            if (result == 0)
            {   
                //var strimg1 = objFP.ImageTextData;    
                var strmin = document.frmmain.objFP.MinTextData;
        alert(strmin);
                document.frmmain.min.value = strmin;
            }
            else
                alert('failed - ' + result);

            return;
        }

        function fnRegister()
        {
            var strmin1 = document.frmmain.min[0].value;
            var strmin2 = document.frmmain.min[1].value;

            if ( objVerify.RegisterForText(strmin1, strmin2) && objVerify.ErrorCode == 0 )
                alert('success- registered');
            else
                alert('failed - ' + objVerify.ErrorCode);

            return;
        }

        function fnVerifyEx()
        {   
            var strmin1 = document.frmmain.min[0].value;
            var strmin2 = document.frmmain.min[1].value;
            var strmin3 = document.frmmain.min[2].value;

            if ( objVerify.VerifyExForText(strmin1, strmin2, strmin3) && objVerify.ErrorCode == 0)
                alert('Success - matched');
            else
                alert('Failed - ' + objVerify.ErrorCode);

            return;
        }

        function fnVerify()
        {   
            var strmin1 = document.frmmain.min[0].value;
            var strmin2 = document.frmmain.min[2].value;

            if ( objVerify.VerifyForText(strmin1, strmin2) && objVerify.ErrorCode == 0 )
                alert('Success - matched');
            else
                alert('Failed - ' + objVerify.ErrorCode);

            return;
        }

        function fnSetimage()
        {
            document.frmmain.objFP.ImageTextData = document.frmmain.img1.value;

            return;
        }
        // -->

        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
        <h4><b>ActiveX Example 1.1 of SecuGen FDx Pro SDK</b></h4>
        <p></p>

        <OBJECT id=objVerify style="LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px" height=0 width=0 
            classid="CLSID:8D613732-7D38-4664-A8B7-A24049B96117" 
            name=objVerify VIEWASTEXT>
        </OBJECT>

        <form name=frmmain>

        Device Type :
        <select name=dev>
        <option value=0>FDP02
        <option value=1>FDU02
        <option value=2>FDU03
        <option value=3>FDU04
        <option selected value=4>FDU05

        </select>

        Instance No. :
        <select name=inc>
        <option value=-1>-1 
        <option value=0>0
        <option value=1>1
        <option value=2>2
        <option value=3>3
        <option value=4>4
        <option value=5>5
        <option value=6>6
        <option value=7>7
        <option value=8>8
        <option value=9>9
        </select>

        <p>
        Template Format:
        <select name=templateFormat>
        <option value=256>ANSI 378
        <option value=512>SG 400
        <option value=768>ISO 19794-2
        </select>

        <input type=button name=open value='Open Device' OnClick='fnOpenDevice();'>
        <p>

        <table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
        <caption> Fingerprint Images </caption>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <OBJECT id=objFP style="LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 149px; TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 182px" height=182 
                width=149 classid="CLSID:D547FDD7-82F6-44e8-AFBA-7553ADCEE7C8" name=objFP VIEWASTEXT>
            <PARAM NAME="CodeName" VALUE="1">
            </OBJECT>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align=center><input type=button name=btnCapture1 value='Capture' OnClick='fnCapture();'></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <p>

        min1 : <input type=text id=min name=min><br>
        <p>
        <input type=button name=btnRegister value='Register' OnClick='fnRegister();' style='width:200px'>
        <br>
        <input type=button name=btnVerify value='VerifyEx' OnClick='fnVerifyEx();' style='width:200px'>
        <br>
        <input type=button name=btnVerify value='Verify' OnClick='fnVerify();' style='width:200px'>

        </form>
        <script>
        fnOpenDevice();
        </script>
        </BODY>
        </HTML>
```

Comment: tried contacting the owners of the scanner? They should have sample API code to use

Comment: I visited their site but nothing there to help me.

Comment: You can try to figure something out from the available Java SDK: https://secugen.com/products/sdk/